# How to set '%' mark in as_sql query (custom Lookup) in Django?

Tags: python, sql, django

I try to select phone numbers from DB ignoring `(`, `)` , `-` symbols and allowing to search by substring

I have a custom lookup

```py
from django.db.models import Lookup
from django.db.models import Field

class ContainsPhoneNo(Lookup):
    lookup_name = 'contains_phone_no'

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        print(lhs_params, rhs_params)
        params = lhs_params + rhs_params
        return "REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(%s, '(', ''), ')', ''), '-', '') ILIKE %s" % (
            lhs, rhs), params

Field.register_lookup(ContainsPhoneNo)
```

So right now, for example, if I filter by `2345`, I can get `(23)-45`, `2-3-45`, etc numbers.   But I want to get also `123456`.   So my query should be

```sql
"REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(%s, '(', ''), ')', ''), '-', '') ILIKE %%s%"
```

But I don't know how to set `%` symbols before and after second `%s`. Django don't allow to set `%` as is inside query string (I also tried `'%'+str(rhs)+'%'` way). So how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering by myself:

Here is two possible solutions:

1. Customize `param_pattern` and use standard `Lookup` class:

```py
from django.db.models import Lookup

class ContainsPhoneNo(Lookup):
    lookup_name = 'contains_phone_no'
    param_pattern = '%%%s%%'

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        params = lhs_params + rhs_params
        return "REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(%s, '(', ''), ')', ''), '-', '') LIKE %s" % (lhs, rhs), params
```

2. Or use `PatternLookup` as parent class (that already has `param_pattern` as I need):

```py
from django.db.models.lookups import PatternLookup

class ContainsPhoneNo(PatternLookup):
    lookup_name = 'contains_phone_no'

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        params = lhs_params + rhs_params
        return "REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(%s, '(', ''), ')', ''), '-', '') LIKE %s" % (lhs, rhs), params
```